# How many functions $f : A \rightarrow A$ are there such that $f \circ f(1) = 2$?

Tags: combinatorics, functions, discrete-mathematics

Given $A = \{1,2,3,4,5\}$, how many functions $f : A \rightarrow A$ are there such that $f \circ f(1) = 2$?

The answer states $4 \times 5^3$, which is close to my answer, but not quite:

You would have $4$ choices for $f(1)$, as $f(1)$ would not be able to equal $1$.

Then you would have $5$ choices for $2, 3, 4, 5$.

So I thought the answer would be $4 \times 5^4$, not $4 \times 5^3$.

Also, given that I cannot answer this first part, I cant answer the next part which is asking for how many **onto** functions there are s.t. $f \circ f(1) = 2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are $4$ choices for $f(1)$, one choice for $f(f(1))$, and  five choices for each of the remaining $3$.

For part two, there are $3!$ choices for the remaining $3$.

Comment: I don't understand how part two can be onto, since everything in the co-domain needs to get hit. But if you have $f(1)$ going to $2$, then $f(2)$ also has to go to $2$, meaning there would be at least one number in the co-domiain that doesn't get hit?

Comment: I guess for part two, $f(1)$ cannot be $1$ or $2$?

Comment: Right you are.  So we get $3\cdot 3!$.

Answer (score 3):

What happens is that when you choose the value of $f(1)$, say $f(1)=2$, then $f(2)$ is already determined, we have that $f(2)=f(f(1))=2$. So, you have $f(3),f(4),f(5)$ free to be chosen, giving you the $5^3$.

Comment: So, if $f$ is onto (which means $f$ is a bijection), then you can discard two cases $f(1)\neq 1$ and $f(1)\neq 2$. So you have three options for $f(1)$. Again, after choosing $f(1)=a$, you have $f(a)=2$.  So,  you have two find a bijective map from the remaining  three $A-\{1,a\}$ to the remaining three possible images $A-\{a,2\}$. These are $3!$. So, the answer is $3*3!$.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution hasn't guaranteed that $f(f(1)) = 2$, only that $f(1) \neq 1$.